# How to fix data output errors from Firestore database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a project where I get data about different films by API and output them by genre.

**Photo to understand what it looks like:**
[image]

Also on my site, email and password authentication is implemented using Firebase. Everything works as it should, data after registration comes to Firebase.

**Example:**
[image]

I need to make it so that when a registered user likes a movie, the data about this movie is saved in the Firestore database and I implemented it.

**Code example where the user likes the movie and it's all saved in Firestore Database:**

```js
export default function Movie({ item }: any) {
  const [like, setLike] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [saved, setSaved] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const { user }: any = UserAuth();
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = React.useState(true);

  const movieID = doc(db, "users", `${user?.email}`);

  const saveShow = async () => {
    if (user?.email) {
      setLike(!like);
      setSaved(true);
      await updateDoc(movieID, {
        savedShows: arrayUnion({
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          img: item.backdrop_path,
        }),
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please log in to save a movie");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item?.backdrop_path}`}
        alt={item?.title}
      />

      <div>
        <p>
          {item?.title}
        </p>
        <p onClick={saveShow}>
          {like ? (
            <FaHeart />
          ) : (
            <FaRegHeart />
          )}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I signed up, liked a few movies and they appeared in my Firestore database.

**Example:**

[image]

Next, I need to display the movies that the user liked in a separate component.

**Here is how I implemented it:**

```js
export default function SavedShows() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState<any>([]);
  const { user }: any = UserAuth();


  React.useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", `${user?.email}`), (doc) => {
      setMovies(doc.data()?.savedShows);
    });
  }, [user?.email]);

  return (
    <>
        <h2>My Movies</h2>
        <div>
          <div>
            {movies.map(({ item, id }: any) => (
              <div
                key={id}>
                <img
                  src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item?.img}`}
                  alt={item?.title}
                />
                <div>
                  <p>
                    {item?.title}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But unfortunately, instead of a list of films that the user liked, I get broken pictures of those same films:
[image]

[image]

I also throw off the code where the functions for registering, logging in and logging out are written ...

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

interface IUserData {
  email: any;
  password: any;
}

interface IContext {
  signUp: any;
  logIn: any;
  logOut: any;
  user: any;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<IContext | null>(null);

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [user, setUser]: any = useState({});

  function signUp({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
      savedShows: [],
    });
  }

  function logIn({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signUp, logIn, logOut, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function UserAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How can I fix the error of displaying movies that the user liked? According to the idea, if the liked films are saved to the database, then everything works as it should and maybe it's the Api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `movies.map` statement. You're destructuring the movie value using `{ item, id }`, but the `item` property doesn't exist on the movie object.

Instead, you could try `{ id, ...item }` to capture all the unused properties in the `item` object.

Or, you could destructure the other properties too:

```js
{movies.map(({ img, id, title }: any) => (
  <div
    key={id}>
    <img
      src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${img}`}
      alt={title}
    />
    <div>
      <p>
        {title}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```